# Как дополнить данные в переменную в json python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Есть json-ответ от `vk_api` вида:

```
[
  {
    "chat_id": 2,
    "blacklist": [],
    "users": [
      {
        "member_id": 284308684,
        "invited_by": 284308684,
        "join_date": 1587617267,
        "is_admin": true,
        "is_owner": true
      },
      {
        "member_id": -191125700,
        "invited_by": 370926160,
        "join_date": 1589806600,
        "is_admin": true
      },
      {
        "member_id": 583018016,
        "can_kick": true,
        "invited_by": 370926160,
        "join_date": 1589817673
      },
      {
        "member_id": 370926160,
        "can_kick": true,
        "invited_by": 284308684,
        "join_date": 1589862613
      },
      {
        "member_id": 591009402,
        "can_kick": true,
        "invited_by": 284308684,
        "join_date": 1589862881
      },
      {
        "member_id": -194062859,
        "invited_by": 284308684,
        "join_date": 1589863783,
        "is_admin": true
      },
      {
        "member_id": 485646343,
        "can_kick": true,
        "invited_by": 284308684,
        "join_date": 1589945360
      }
    ],
    "admins": []
  }
]
```

Мне надо добавить в admins админов, а также warn для каждого юзера в users. Нужна помощь с реализацией

Comment: 1. Используйте для всех пользователей одинаковые поля (т.е. у всех будут поля `is_admin`, `is_owner`, `can_kick` и т.д.). 2. Не нужно делать отдельный список `admins`, вы можете получать список админов из списка пользователей (как раз благодаря соответствующему полю)

Comment: это ответ на мой запрос к vk_api. Даже так я не знаю как к нужному юзеру добавить поля.

Comment: @Alik `for item in json: for user in item["users"]: user["warn"] = "warn"`.